# Large number of kernel messages 'testing the buffer'

Tags: ubuntu, syslogd

My syslog shows hundreds of successive messages:

...
Jun  4 09:18:21 www kernel: [55101.038066] testing the buffer
Jun  4 09:18:21 www kernel: [55101.038181] testing the buffer
Jun  4 09:18:21 www kernel: [55101.040872] testing the buffer
...

Where are these coming from? Ubuntu 20.

Comment: I got the same but on Ubuntu 18 LTS. Not exactly sure at the time it started.